# Meaning of GTK critical stderr message

Tags: gnome, gtk

Only slightly worried about this, but I don't like the word critical.I uninstalled Evolution and reinstalled it, got it to work by removing 4 files in the /.conf folder. Everything is working fine but this message keeps popping up in my terminal. Logs has no entries to this effect. Any ideas, please?

```shell
evolution-alarm-notify:2998: Gtk-CRITICAL**-11.14:10:1006:
gtk_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK IS A WIDGET (widget) failed
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Unless you are developing Evolution, you can ignore them.

Answer (score 4):

The message is generated by GTK+, which was used to build the complaining application.

The `2998` is the process ID, and `gtk_get_scale_factor` is the GTK+ function that encountered the issue.

In short, some function passed a non-widget handle to this function, and the function returned garbage.

Its important to fix... and great that it complains, as it could have gone unnoticed, and could lead to exploits, crashes, etc - that's why it's critical.

Most important of all... it adds a sense of melodrama and importance, to even mundane applications.

Comment: It doesn't return garbage, it returns the number 1, and it won't lead to any exploits or crashes, because it's explicitly handled. They just used a logging function that has "melodrama" as its only option.

Comment: I think the point is that it could have, if those checks weren't in place.